# Hide Javascript error message from browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, client-side

I found this code sample on one of the questions;

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, linenumber) {  

 //make ajax call with all error details and log error directly into the elmah database

 //show friendly error msg here to user

 //hide error from browser
 return true; 
}
```

What does *'hide error from browser'* means and how can I do that?

I didn't know such a thing exists and I give it a try with try-catch block. After an error occurred, I realized that browser still shows the error. How can I hide error from browser?

**UPDATE**

I tried following code and put that inside the head section of my all pages but noting happened;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function () {

    window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {

        alert(errorMsg);

        // Just let default handler run.
        return true;
    }

})();

</script>
```

Comment: Re: your updated question - nothing will happen until there is an error.

Comment: @adam :) of course I raised an error but still nothing happened

Comment: @seoul on Chrome, when I open up the js console, errors are still there when I use try-catch block. I don't want that.

Comment: They will still appear in the js console - that's what the console is there for.

Comment: @adam no way to hide I guess or we need to dive deeply.

Comment: @tugberk the console is a developer tool - it's there for developers and will not show to end users unless they actively enable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the function returns true, this prevents the firing of the default event handler.

It's just the way the browser behaves if this function returns true.

[See more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onerror#Parameters)

Answer (score 5):

use: try...catch

```
function message()
{
    try
    {
        adddlert("Welcome guest!");
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        txt = "There was an error on this page.\n\n";
        txt += "Error description: " + err.description + "\n\n";
        txt += "Click OK to continue.\n\n";
        alert(txt);
    }
}
```

more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Answer (score 1):

Adding window.onerror function to the head section and returning true would stop logging the errors events to the browser console.

As @Decko mentioned returning true prevents the firing of the default event handler.

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-mfattr?file=index.html